# How do I retrieve all the markers in gmap4rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-maps, gmaps4rails

```
  Gmaps.store.handler = Gmaps.build('Google');
  Gmaps.store.handler.buildMap({ provider: {}, internal: {id: 'map'}}, function(){
    mapping.forEach(function(item) {
      Gmaps.store.marker = Gmaps.store.handler.addMarker(
        {
          ...
        }
      );
    });
    console.log(Gmaps.store.handler);
    Gmaps.store.handler.bounds.extendWith(Gmaps.store.marker);
    Gmaps.store.handler.fitMapToBounds();
  })
```

I'm adding markers one by one. But I would like the map to extend and cover all the markers. How do I retrieve the markers. So I can pass them into extendWith()?

Answer (score 0):

Just had to shift the extendWith() into my iterator and pass each marker into it.

```
mapping.forEach(function(item) {
  Gmaps.store.marker = Gmaps.store.handler.addMarker(
    {
      ...
    }
  );
  Gmaps.store.handler.bounds.extendWith(Gmaps.store.marker);
});
```